# "delims=#+#" - more then 1 character as delimiter

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Is it possible to define a delimiter which is not limited to 1 character? Based on the title's example, I would like to define my separator as e.g.
'#+#'. Textfiles/lines can contain both characters, but there is very little chance you'll come across that particular substring/text combo.

Comment: Delimiter for `for`? No, only single chars are possible. Delimiter for `csv`? As far as I know also Excel supports only single character delimiters

Answer (score 4):

No, you can not use a *string* as a delimiter in the `delims=` clause. Of course you can include the string, but it will be handled as a set of separate characters that will be used as delimiters, not as a delimiter string.

If you really need to split on a string, the fastest approach could be to replace the *delimiter string* by a character not included in the data and use this character as delimiter

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "delims=" %%a in ("this is a +test!! #+# of string #splitting#") do (
        set "buffer=%%a"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        (for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=¬" %%b in ("!buffer:#+#=¬!") do (
            endlocal
            echo full line    : [%%a]
            echo first token  : [%%b]
            echo second token : [%%c]
        )) || if "!!"=="" endlocal 
    )
```

**Note**: The `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` is needed to be able to read the variable changed inside the `for` loop retrieving the data (here simulated directly including a string). Then, inside the `for` loop that tokenizes the readed line, delayed expansion is disabled to avoid problems with the `!` characters (if delayed expansion is active, they will be consumed by the parser). This is the reason for the `endlocal` inside the loop.

As we are doing a string replacement and it is possible to end with a string composed of only delimiters, it is possible that the `do` clause of the inner `for` will not be executed, so the final `if` is included to ensure that the `enabledelayedexpansion` is cancelled.

Comment: ...concerning the final `endlocal`: so `for` sets the `ErrorLevel` if its body is never executed?

Comment: @aschipfl, no, it does not *set* the `errorlevel` variable, but in `cmd` most of the commands are coded as functions that will return an exit sucess/failure value, and the conditional execution operator uses this value to determine code execution. If the `for /f` does not iterate over any line, its asociated function will return a failure code but will not set the `errorlevel`. You can find more information about this behaviour  in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30714985/2861476). Read at least the answers (this is the logical order) from dbenham, eryksun and my own answer.

Comment: #MC ND: so that's how humility feels like :) That said: way to complicated for myself/ITteam. Done some testing with the ASCII_ANSI, and probably something is these lines:    @echo off
rem *** ASCII Alt+221
set MyDelim=¦

dir *.* /b >dirlist.txt

Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set Count=testingValue
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (dirlist.txt) do (

set AddValue=%%i%MyDelim%%Count%

echo [!AddValue!]
)
pause

Comment: @Badt_Paul, Sorry, sure I'm missing something but I don't see the a clear relation between the question (asking how to split the data) and the code in your comment. Is it trying to generate the data that later you will have to split?

Comment: The goal is to ensure that the delimiter always works; is unique. Hence a multi_char delimiter would have been the solution. Since this is not possible, the next 'best thing' would be to use a delimiter that is hardly/not-at-all used. I have (can have) control over the delimiter, not its contents. But the generated files are "pure" ASCII (not UTF for the moment). And so to answer your question: I receive the delimited file, which I then need to "split".

Comment: Wow, that's weird, @MCND! up to now I thought the conditional execution operators rely on `ErrorLevel`, but that's not the case apparently; thank you for the _very_ ineresting information!

Answer (score 4):

I recently discovered an interesting trick that allows to use a multi-character string as delimiter to split a larger string in a very simple way; the method does not use any `for` command, but perform the split *in just one line!* Here it is:

```
@echo off

set "str=this is a +test!! #+# of string #splitting#"

set "first=%str:#+#=" & set "last=%"

echo full line    : [%str%]
echo first token  : [%first%]
echo last token   : [%last%]
```

This method also allows to split a large string in several parts and store *all of them* in an array. Further details at [dos batch iterate through a delimited string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524928/dos-batch-iterate-through-a-delimited-string/33091367#33091367)

Comment: I was about to ask if this could be extended to multiple (3+) seperated values, but your link shows such example. Did not test it yet, but this is indeed what I've been looking for. (I also confess that I can not explain why this is working...)

Comment: @Badt_Paul: If you want to review another example of this method with more explanations, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32578014/how-to-extract-version-number-in-a-windows-batch-file/33112178#33112178

Comment: Strangely, this neat trick doesn't seem to work when you simply place the logic between parenthesis ( set "str= ... echo last :[%last%]  ) ...

Comment: @RKO: Yes, but this is an inherent limitaton of `%variable%` expansion: `( set "var=Not works" & echo %var% )`. You may `EnableDelayedExpansion` and then use `( set "var=Works" & echo !var! )`